# How to set TextView text from a different class?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set a textview text when the user location changes.  All the code for the GPS portion works. I have been testing using Log();

Now instead of using Log, I wish to display the same information on the main layout, but the LocationChanged event is in a different class so I don't have access to the layout.

```
public class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener
{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        Log.v("kjdv", location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
        //I would like to set a textview here, but don't have access to the object
    }
}
```

This class gets created here:

```
public class gps extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SetupLocationListener();
}

public void SetupLocationListener()
{
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener(this);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}
```

So how, from the myLocationListener class can I set text in the onLocationChanged event?

Thanks!

Comment: Make your `LocationListener` class an `inner` class of your `ListActivity`.

Comment: Wasn't even aware that was an option. Thanks.

Comment: Because an Android `Activity` is a 'special case' class primarily used for UI representation, and the fact it can never be instantiated directly, this is a common problem. Declaring a class which works as a 'listener' (including `BroadcastReceiver` classes) and also `AsyncTask` classes, for example, as nested classes simplifies things a great deal. It isn't always the best approach and you can do it in other ways but it does get more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 2 options.

one is just like as MisterSquonk said. keeping the Location listener as the inner class and the other one is to pass the object of the textView to the constructor of the mylocationlistener. Dont forget to handle null clause in second step.